# Equations involving solving for X

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My teacher doesn't explain how to solve equations:
$5x-4=2$.
They ask me to solve for $x$. 
Can someone help?

Comment: The common phrase is to "collect like terms".  That is, start by adding or subtracting the same thing from both sides of the equation so that you have only $X$ terms on one side and constant terms on the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$5x-4=2$
Add 4 to both sides
$5x=6$
Divide by 5, therefore
$x=6/5=1.2$

Comment: OMG TY SO MUCH!